# Matrix of Linear Operator in the given basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, change-of-basis

What do we understand when we say the matrix of the linear operator $A $ in the basis $ E $ is $ M $?

Acording to the definition

$ A: L_1 \rightarrow L_2 $

$M: V_n(K) \rightarrow V_M(K)  $

the basis of $\ L_1 $ is $\ E_1 $ and the basis of $ L_2 $ is $ E_2 $. Then $ AE_1=ME_2 $ and here $ M  $ is the matrix of the linear operator $ A  $ in the bases $ E_1 $ and $ E_2 $.

Comment: Excuse me, eactly what are you asking? It's not clear to me.

Comment: What do we understand when we say the matrix of the linear operator A in the basis E is M? Don't we have to mention 2 basises?

Comment: Maybe they are referring to an endomorphism.

Comment: You mean when $\ A:L->L $ ?

Comment: yes, with the same base $E$ on $L$ as domain and on $L$ as codomain.